# how do I type fast using one hand?

Tags: keyboard

Recently I have my right back wounded, so I can't type using right hand. I feel it is very difficult to type using only left hand on the standard keyboard, especially when I need to capitalize characters, or when I need to use shift or controls. For example, if I need to use the shift, I need first type shift five times and the promote pops up and I click yes, then I can use shift once.

I search the net for one handed keyboard, like the following：

[image]

but they are for gaming only. The other characters are missing which I need to use them coding.

**I want some sort of typing mechanism(software or hardware) which can keep my left hand in one place (because lifting or moving it will cause a little pain on right part of my back), and I can type all the characters and symbols fast and convenient.**

Comment: Have you considered Speech recognition? You say what you want to type rather than actually typing it. If you really need a keyboard, any keyboard will do, it just takes a lot of practice and hand movement. Typing is a 2 hand operation.

Comment: @LPChip speech recognition is not my first option, I mean I want to type without lifting my left hand away from keyboard, just moving my fingers are ok.

Comment: You'll probably want a specially designed keyboard, like [this](https://www.maltron.com/store/p1/Maltron_Single_Hand_Keyboards_-_UK_English.html) - unfortunately they aren't cheap.

Comment: @Attie That's cool, but yes, it is too expensive and not easy to find

Comment: I was going to suggest [8pen](http://www.8pen.com) or its descendent [VI8](https://github.com/flide/VI8), but unfortunately that's Android only and I guess you're programming on Linux or Windows.

Comment: How long term is the solution you're looking for? When your right hand will recover? That determines the investment worth putting in learning a completely new setup. Also what text do you type: just plain English / are you a programmer / do you often need to type special characters? I use swipe typing on my phone be and it's quite convenient with one hand.

Comment: @MátéJuhász two month I will recover. After that, typing using one hand will probably be a hobby. I mainly type plain language, and yes, you can think me as a programmer,

Comment: @LPChip Do you have any good sugestions to use speech recognition? To use it post an SU answer and write a piece of code using it, for example...

Comment: @buzhidao I don't actually. I don't need it myself, but as an IT professional, when someone has a problem, I always look what the actual problem is that needs to be solved, not what the user wants for a solution (The A/B problem). And then look for a good solution based on that. That's why I suggested speech recognition. That is a far better solution than a special keyboard in most cases. I don't have experience though, but google will be your friend, no doubt. If you have a phone, you can even do something like: RDP from your phone to your pc and use its capabilities.

Comment: @LPChip For non-programming tasks, speech recognition is indeed the best solution for most people.  However, actually programming in most languages with speech recognition is extremely painful, because expressing a program in natural language terms that the software will recognize and interpret correctly is usually extremely difficult (believe me, I've actually had to do this myself before, it's an experience I wouldn't wish on my worst enemy).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn It's hard to use speech recognition to input character by character, often it recognize words by words. Also, special characters such as `, : ;` are hard to input, because they will recognize them as `comma column separation`

Answer (score 2):

First off, nothing you choose to do is going to be easy right off the bat.  There will be a learning curve, regardless.

So, based on that, what are your options?

1. Actually get one of those gaming keypads.  The really nice ones will let you remap *all* the buttons however you want and usually have at least 6-key rollover. 
   With such a pad, you can put together a layout with 4-5 modifier keys and do a simple 2 or 3 stroke chording arrangement (so, common letters require none of the modifier keys, less common ones require one modifier, etc).  This has a couple of extra advantages too, namely that most of them have some built-in pointer movement option that's easy to use without moving your hand, and that you can bind all the dead-key combinations (those which you don't map to regular characters) to macros.  One of my friends actually does this for almost everything (he originally did it just for gaming, but he got to the point that he's better typing that way than he is with a conventional keyboard), and can quite often code more efficiently tha most of his colleagues (though he has optimized the layout for his coding in the primary language he works with).
2. See if your system offers any one-handed keyboard layouts.  I'm pretty sure at least Linux and Windows have one-handed Dvorak layouts for both left and right hands.  Such layouts *usually* assume no chording, but some may also be chording layouts.  At the utmost extreme, you can sometimes find layouts that only use 5 keys and chord *everything* (I've got a couple of blind friends who use such a layout regularly).
3. Look into creating your own keymap for this.  This is a bit of a hassle, but can easily produce something that works more intuitively for you, but will be the least portable option.
4. While this might sound rather stupid, look into text prediction software.  This may provide just enough to cover handling for those odd stretches to deal with things like capital letters.  This is the approach I've used in the past on the rare occasions when i've had to operate a computer one-handed and couldn't use speech recognition software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already a touch typist and have macOS, try using   Keyb: the one-handed keyboard
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/keyb-the-one-handed-keyboard/id1588579580?mt=12

After installing the application, regular keyboard can be used as one handed keyboard. Your **spacebar** will act like Modifier key.
By holding **spacebar** key, you are mirroring the keybaord temporarily.

The keyboard will work normal, the moment **you press and hold spacebar and type**, you get the mirror of the keyboard.

If you are right handed person, ***j k l ;*** can be pressed normally.
the same keys willl print ***f d s a*** when holding spacebar and typing the key.

[image]